# Swift-ObjC mix match, Other swift files not recognized

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project with ObjC base. 
Following is what I did.

- Drag and drop `file1.swift` file in the project.
- Asked by Xcode to create bridging header file `productname-bridging-header.h` file. Created
- There is another file `file2.swift`. `file1.swift` imports the other file.
- But `file2.swift` is not recognised by `file1.swift`.
- Define Module is set to yes.
- Path for bridging header is correct.
- Objective C generated interface header name (automatically) set to `productname-swift.h`. But cannot locate the file.

Comment: Are the files in separate modules?

Comment: @moni15 No. ProjectName -> AppDelegate.h|.m, ViewControlle.h|.m, file1.swift, file2.swift

Comment: Are both give access control of `open` ?